# MySQL x Java - Raising Exception

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, exception

I've been learning MySQL this past few days. Previously, I develop with PostgreSQL. Maybe I missed something and wasn't able to find the right tutorial or question here in SO. If this is a duplicate, please feel free to give a link.
I'll go straight to the point, my question would be:
-This is written in PostgreSQL copied directly from my procedure, is there something similar to this in MySQL? (Don't mind the String).

```
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'app_get_rpt_doctor_signature_all(text) %',
            'OTHERS ' || SQLERRM;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`DECLARE ... HANDLER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/declare-handler.html) to catch exceptions and, since MySQL v5.5, you can [`SIGNAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/signal.html) or [`RESIGNAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/resignal.html) to raise your own / pass on existing exceptions respectively; within those statements, one can `SET MESSAGE_TEXT` to specify a custom message, but sadly it is not possible to access the message text of the existing (handled) exception.

Therefore, you could do:

```sql
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
  SET MESSAGE_TEXT := 'app_get_rpt_doctor_signature_all(text) OTHERS'
;
```

Or `RESIGNAL` with the message unchanged:

```sql
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  RESIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
;
```